# How do I add a column with an auto-incremental name to a MySql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, type-conversion

I'm using VB.net to write a MYSQL application and one feature I need to add is the ability to add a column for each week that my employees worked. For example I want the first column to be called "W1" and the next one to be "W2" and so on, right up to "W52". so my question is how would I add a column to my table and have it's name add 1 to its current value? if there wasn't any letters in the name it would be easy but I need it to have the "W" in the title as well to avoid confusion. to add the column I have this:

```
ALTER TABLE manager ADD W1 MEDIUMINT;
```

i just need the part that adds an INTEGER to a VARCHAR datatype if possible... Maybe there should be some sort of data type conversion involved?

**UPDATE:** 
what i want to display in my vb.net form is a datagrid view that looks exactly like this:

[image: Sample from my spread sheet]

Just to explain further, the black bar at the very top are the date stamps for each week, I would like to have this included in the datagridview if possible but it is not required. Under each week column the employees will be entering the percents they worked (example: 20%, or 0.20 is one day of work) I know this is an odd way of doing things but it's mandatory... and I was wondering if it were possible to automate the creation of these columns rather than me having to manually enter them.

Comment: Generally, when you have situations like this you are way off in your database design. Consider having a separate table for weeks.

Comment: I'm not answering your question, but I think you'd better create a new table `(userid INT, week SMALLINT, data_you_need)` and add data there for every user/week instead of in columns on original table!!!

Comment: how would creating a new table solve anything? im simply trying to add the columns using non-query statements instead of having to add 52 columns myself. im sorry, i should have been more clear. What i want is some sort of recursive check and add statement to see if "W1" exists, if it doesn't, add it , if it does then go to next statement.

Comment: @daniel: Why do you need a column for every week? I would simply create a Table `WorkingTime` with `fiEmployee` as FK and `startTime` and `endTime`(`datetime)` as fields. The rest is SQL(f.e. to get the weeknumber from a datetime).

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Because im trying to make the datagrid controls in my program as similar to my spreadsheet as possible as i am already very familiar with it.

Comment: however id be interested to see an example of your suggestion (or a preview of the final result at least)

Comment: Database is not a spreadsheet. Please do read up on normalization.

Comment: im well aware of the difference, all im doing is creating a program to display the information from my database (which came from my spreadsheet) and allow other employees and managers to add or delete things on it.

Comment: i originally was using a .xls spreadsheet and had to email it to all the project managers with the changes ive made but that was becoming such a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 possible solution would be to create 2 new tables

tbl_week:
  weekid, weekno, start_date, end_date

tbl_weeks_worked:
  userid, weekid, worked

and pivot the data in the database. (alternativly you could do this in VB.NET)

if you want the header, you will need to union 2 pivoted queries

e.g:

```
SELECT '' as userid,
      MAX(CASE WHEN w.weekno = 1 THEN w.start_date END)) AS 'W1', 
      MAX(CASE WHEN w.weekno = 2 THEN w.start_date END)) AS 'W2', 
      MAX(CASE WHEN w.weekno = 3 THEN w.start_date END)) AS 'W3', 
      ........ etc 
FROM tbl_week w
WHERE w.start_date >= start AND w.end_date <= enddate 

UNION ALL

SELECT  
  userid,  
  SUM(CASE WHEN w.weekno = 1 AND ww.weekid IS NOT NULL THEN worked ELSE 0 END)) AS 'W1', 
  SUM(CASE WHEN w.weekno = 2 AND ww.weekid IS NOT NULL THEN worked ELSE 0 END)) AS 'W2', 
  SUM(CASE WHEN w.weekno = 3 AND ww.weekid IS NOT NULL THEN worked ELSE 0 END)) AS 'W3', 
  ........ etc 
FROM tbl_week w
LEFT JOIN tbl_weeks_worked ww ON ww.weekid = w.weekid
WHERE w.start_date >= start AND w.end_date <= enddate 
GROUP BY userid;
```

Note: (this will only work for a single year view)

Comment: ok, you just need to add a column to hold the portion of day worked, have edited the answer

Comment: let me know what they are and I can help you

Comment: it doesn't specify, it just says "you have an SQL syntax error in one or more or your statements, please refer to your MySql User Manual for more information"